# I'm a Philippine passport holder, can I go to Turkey with my Schengen visa without visiting the Schengen area first?

Tags: visas, turkey, filipino-citizens, e-visas

[image]

I have a valid German national visa (Type D) (valid March 1-August 31, 2017), and I am a Filipino Citizen. We cannot visit Turkey without purchasing an e-Visa and without a valid Schengen Visa.

Can I go to Istanbul first before actually going to the Schengen area?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wish to *enter* Turkey and not merely *transit* through, you may.

Courtesy [SkyTeam and timaticweb<sup>2</sup>](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/): For Filipino passport holders resident in the Philippines:

> **Visa issuance:**
>
> Nationals of Philippines with a normal passport can obtain an e-visa before departure at [www.evisa.gov.tr](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/apply/) if they have a valid on arrival visa or a residence permit issued by Ireland (Rep.), USA, United Kingdom or a Schengen Member State.
>
> **Additional information:**
>
> Visitors who require a visa, must also hold proof of hotel reservation and documents for their next destination.
>
> Visitors exceeding the period for which they are allowed to stay must report to the immigration police and obtain a permit of residence ("Ikamet Vesikasi") which must be produced upon departure.
>
> **Important:**
>
> Visitors who require a visa and do not hold return/onward ticket could be refused entry.

A Schengen `D` visa counts as a residence permit within the Schengen area.

An e-Visa ($20) would be valid for a single entry of up to 30 days from the date of arrival in Turkey but may be extended if you apply to your local Police Station for a residency permit.

Your passport must contain at least one unused visa page and have [an expiration date at least 60 days beyond the “duration of stay”](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/passport-validity-requirements-while-entering-turkey-in-accordance-with-law-on-foreigners-and-international-protection.en.mfa).

Comment: Well I paid $43 on Jan 01 for same Turkish single entry e-visa, based on Schengen Visa with Indian Passport.

Comment: Thank you. So it doesnt matter that I haven't been to the Schengen area yet and haven't really "activated" my visa? @pnuts

Comment: @DavChana I paid $20 for an e-visa from the website. Where did you pay the $43?

Comment: @DavidJ. [https://www.evisa.gov.tr](https://www.evisa.gov.tr) I checked just now, its $20 for Philippines Passport Holder, & $43 for Indian Passport Holder :(